# Add route to NavigationContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

how can i add a navigation Route to a Tab Navigator or in general in a NavigationContainer without adding a new Tab.Screen. Try to add Navigation in child components.

```
Her is my Navigation Container in App.js

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenTwo" component={ShoppingScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenThree" component={RecipeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenFour" component={DiscoverScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: what you mean exactly, ex. HomeScreen to have HomeScreen/x, HomeScreen/y ?

Comment: In the moment i have a Navigation with 4 Bottom-Tabs for each main route-category. Now i want navigate in each of this Tab Screen in deeper sections of the App, but not expand the main BottomTab Navigation. is it so understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Screen options with nested navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/)

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="A"
        component={A}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="B"
        component={B}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        .....
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
 )
}
```